# django efficient queryset on related fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

Suppose you have the following models

```
class User:
    pass

class Tag:
    pass

class UserTag: # user is interested in tag
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)

class Blog:
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

For a given user, I want to get all blogs that user expressed his interests by `UserTag`

something like
Blog.objects.filter(tags__usertag_set__user=user_id)

I can do this in multiple steps but is it the best way to do it?

```
user_tags = UserTag.objects.filter(user=user)
result = Blog.objects.none()
for user_tag in user_tags:
    tag = user_tag.tag
    q = tag.blog_set.all()  
    result = result | q
```

This inevitably iterates all user_tags and bad...

Comment: I would try `Blog.objects.filter(usertag__user=user_id)`. Also, `UserTag` is a many-to-many through-model for users essentially.

Comment: Hi Wtower! Blog doesn't have access to usertag though..

Comment: It does, check the django documentation on reverse FK lookups.

Comment: I believe it should: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships give it a try and if it works I can explain in an answer.

Comment: does it? it's completlely conceptual setup, it'll take some time to try it out..

Comment: don't you mean `Blog.objects.filter(tags__usertag__user=user_id)` ? and I think it may work.. (I have not enough data to be certain..)

Comment: UserTag is not a `through` table for Blog's manytomany field.

Comment: I see "Cannot resolve keyword 'usertag' into field. Choices are:..."

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
user_tags = list(UserTag.objects.filter(creator=user).values_list('id', flat=True))
Blog.objects.filter(tags__in=user_tag)
```